# sendgrid unauthorized. Wrong credentials - php

Tags: php, sendgrid

I'm trying to implement sendgrid to my project and I have a basic function running the following:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php'; // If you're using Composer (recommended)
        // Comment out the above line if not using Composer
        // require("<PATH TO>/sendgrid-php.php");
        // If not using Composer, uncomment the above line and
        // download sendgrid-php.zip from the latest release here,
        // replacing <PATH TO> with the path to the sendgrid-php.php file,
        // which is included in the download:
        // https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases
        $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
        $email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
        $email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
        $email->addTo("tiernoyt@gmail.com", "Example User");
        $email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
        $email->addContent(
            "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
        );
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($_ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']);
        try {
            $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
            print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
            print_r($response->headers());
            print $response->body() . "\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
      }
```

I get the error "permission denied: wrong credentials". I have the environmental variable set, I tried to put the value of the key with quotes and no quotes. It is also in my sendgrid.env file (which is gitignored) as the following line

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

If I change the code to `$apiKey = 'xxxxxx'; $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($api);` then it works. So it is obviously an error fetching the variable but I'm not sure as to why

Comment: So did you try `echo $_ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'];`  to see what is being found?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it returned `undefined index 'SENDGRID_API_KEY'` and I also did `print_r($_ENV);` which returns an empty array. However if i run SET in my command line, the variable is listed

Comment: Can you look at your `php.ini` file and tell us what `variables_order` is set to? Because the `E` parameter is not normally set, specially on LIVE Hosted envoronments.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is set to GPCS

Comment: So thats why the `$_ENV` is not being set. It would have to be `GPCSE` But before you think I will add the `E` That WONT be set on hosted sites, so your code should probably use `getenv()` instead

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried to use `getenv()` and it had the same result. Should the `SENDGRID_API_KEY` environmental variable be set as a user or system environmental variable?

Comment: Again, if you move this code to a LIVE real hosted server, are you going to be able to add things to either of those as part of your hosting package, I doubt it